# Why is the cube rendered without colors?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Please advise why is the cube rendered without colors although my VBO contains colors? What am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

**Voxel.java**

```
    package cz.rv.cubeworld.mesh;

    import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;

    import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

    public class Voxel {

        /**
               H_______________G
               /.             /|
              / .            / |
            D/_____________C/  |
            |   .          |   |
            |   .          |   |
            |   ...........|...|
            | . E          |  /F
            |______________|/
            A              B
        */

        private static final float[] vertexData = {
                // Position             // Normal               // Color

                // Back side - E H G F
                -1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f,    0.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // E
                 1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f,    0.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // F
                 1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f,    0.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // G
                -1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f,    0.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // H

                // Bottom side - F B A E
                 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // F
                 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // B
                -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // A
                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // E

                // Right side - F G C B
                 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,     1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // F
                 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,     1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // G
                 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,     1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // C
                 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,     1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // B

                // Top side - C G H D
                 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // C
                 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // G
                -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // H
                -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // D

                // Left side - A D H E
                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,    -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // A
                -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,    -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // D
                -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,    -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // H
                -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,    -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // E

                // Front side - A D C B
                -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,      0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // A
                -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,      0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // D
                 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,      0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // C
                 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,      0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // B
        };

        private static final int TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_VERTICES = 24;
        private static final int VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE_SIZE = 10 * Float.BYTES;      // In bytes
        private static final int VERTEX_POSITION_SIZE = 3;                      // In floats
        private static final int VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE = 4;                         // In floats
        private static final int FIRST_VERTEX_POSITION_POINTER = 0;             // In bytes
        private static final int FIRST_VERTEX_NORMAL_POINTER = 3 * Float.BYTES; // In bytes
        private static final int FIRST_VERTEX_COLOR_POINTER = 6 * Float.BYTES;  // In bytes

        private final int vertexBufferObjectHandle;
        private final FloatBuffer vertexBufferObject;

        public Voxel() {
            vertexBufferObject = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexData.length);  // Allocate direct float buffer
            vertexBufferObject.put(vertexData).flip();  // Write data to the buffer and reset the position to zero

            vertexBufferObjectHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers(); // Create named buffer object
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObjectHandle);  // Hey, GL, we will be using named buffer object we just generated
            GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);   // Write vertexBufferObject data to our named buffer object
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Tell GL we aren't using any named buffer since now
        }

        public void render(float x, float y, float z, float xrot, float yrot, float zrot) {
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();

            GL11.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
            GL11.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glRotatef(zrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

            GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
            GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObjectHandle);

            GL11.glVertexPointer(VERTEX_POSITION_SIZE, GL11.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE_SIZE, FIRST_VERTEX_POSITION_POINTER);
            GL11.glColorPointer(VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE, GL11.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE_SIZE, FIRST_VERTEX_COLOR_POINTER);
            GL11.glNormalPointer(GL11.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE_SIZE, FIRST_VERTEX_NORMAL_POINTER);

            GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_VERTICES);

            GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
            GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        }
    }
```

**DisplayExample.java**

package cz.rv.cubeworld;

```
import cz.rv.cubeworld.mesh.Voxel;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

public class DisplayExample {

    private float xrot;
    private float yrot;
    private float zrot;
    private float lightAmbient[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    private float lightDiffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    private float lightPosition[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f, 1.0f };
    private Voxel voxel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DisplayExample displayExample = new DisplayExample();
        displayExample.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            init();
            voxel = new Voxel();
            while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
                render();
                Display.update();
                Display.sync(60);
                xrot += 0.2f;
                yrot += 0.3f;
                zrot += 0.1f;
            }

            cleanup();
        } catch (LWJGLException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private void init() throws LWJGLException, IOException {
        createWindow();
        initGL();
    }

    private void createWindow() throws LWJGLException {
        DisplayMode displayMode = null;
        for (DisplayMode mode : Display.getAvailableDisplayModes()) {
            if (mode.getWidth() == 640 && mode.getHeight() == 480 && mode.getBitsPerPixel() == 24) {
                displayMode = mode;
                break;
            }
        }
        Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
        Display.setTitle("CubeWorld");
        Display.create();
    }

    private void initGL() {
        //GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Enable Texture Mapping
        GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH); // Enable Smooth Shading
        GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Black Background
        GL11.glClearDepth(1.0); // Depth Buffer Setup
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enables Depth Testing
        GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL); // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION); // Select The Projection Matrix
        GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix
        GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight(), 0.1f, 100.0f); // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select The Modelview Matrix
        GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST); // Really Nice Perspective Calculations

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

        ByteBuffer lightBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16);
        lightBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, (FloatBuffer) lightBuffer.asFloatBuffer().put(lightAmbient).flip()); // Setup The Ambient Light
        GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, (FloatBuffer) lightBuffer.asFloatBuffer().put(lightDiffuse).flip()); // Setup The Diffuse Light
        GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_POSITION, (FloatBuffer) lightBuffer.asFloatBuffer().put(lightPosition).flip()); // Position The Light
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT1);  // Enable Light One
    }

    private void cleanup() {
        Display.destroy();
    }

    private void render() {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        voxel.render(0, 0, -5, xrot, yrot ,zrot);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```